# Jquery On Dynamic Load raido buttons how do i get its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am loading this category div on ajax call on the page load then i want to call another ajax functions with the value of the this radio button that is selected.

In my HTML i have

```
<div id="category_data">
<br>
<input type="radio" checked="" value="01807000" name="invoiceid" onclick="getInvoiceRelatedData('01807000');">
July 2015 - New Charges: $71.51
<br>
<input type="radio" value="01778565" name="invoiceid" onclick="getInvoiceRelatedData('01778565');">
June 2015 - New Charges: $71.02
<br>
<input type="radio" value="01743295" name="invoiceid" onclick="getInvoiceRelatedData('01743295');">
May 2015 - New Charges: $71.32
<br>
</div>
```

My JS looks like

```
 <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            getCategoryRelatedData();
            alert_s=jQuery("input[name='invoiceid']:checked").val();
            alert(alert_s);//
        getInvoiceRelatedData(alert_s);
        }); // end of ready function
```

Actually what i wanted to do is load the default data selected on the page load rather than user has to click on it.

Comment: You can do it in `jQuery.ajax.success()` or use `jQuery.promise()` to do this.

Comment: yeah but the UI doenst allow me to call the data in the ajax success because then it has to be modified so much to create that page

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you can't use ajax success to do this job. But if you can use jquery and send ajax request, you can try promise to get value after your ajax done.

I try to simulate your condition and do it in jsfiddle.

```
function getCategoryRelatedData(){
    console.log('getCategoryRelatedData...');
    return $.ajax(/* what ever you want to do*/);
}

function getInvoiceRelatedData(){
    console.log('getInvoiceRelatedData...');
    var alert_s=$("input[name='invoiceid']:checked").val();
    alert(alert_s);//
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    getCategoryRelatedData().promise().done(getInvoiceRelatedData);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jul101/85uoe54o/